# How does macOS assign hostnames

Tags: macos, hostname

I'm using some application software which I have installed on an Azure VM. I have a MacBook laptop which I use to connect to the Azure VM, using Microsoft's Remote Desktop client for Mac software.

The software installed on the Windows Azure VM is proprietary (developed and licenced by a third party company), and only compatible with Windows (hence not running it locally on the MacBook). I've gone down the Azure route (as opposed to Bootcamp or Parallels for example) as I can take advantage of the cloud model - no worries on operating system licence costs, updates, maintenance and I can also turn it off when I don't need it (to save energy and cost).

The licence is for one user and one machine only, which is fine for my needs. So far as I understand it, the software's licencing algorithm takes the network hostname of the installed machine (i.e. Azure machine) and also the hostname of any remote connected client (i.e. my MacBook), concatenates both hostnames together, applies some sort of algorithm (presumably some sort of one-way hash), and records this as a HostID. The same algorithm is repeated on each sign-in and compared with the originally recorded HostID (thereby preventing someone else remotely connecting and using the software).

My problem is that my MacBook's hostname seems to be variable. Sometimes it is "mymacbook" and sometimes it is "mymacbook.local". If I connect to the Azure server, I think I can see my local hostname by going to task manager > users [tab] > client name [column - needed to add by right-clicking on the header and selecting column]. The variability of my client's hostname is causing the licencing to fail when it is not exactly the same as it was on the first installation.

I did a bit of research - if I understand correctly, the hostname is assigned to my MacBook by my local router as I am using DHCP? Also, Apple Bonjour, which is Apples mDNS implementation can cause .local to be appended onto the end of the hostname (e.g. when my MacBook is connected to or is in range of other devices)? Is this right or am I barking up the wrong tree!? Just trying to figure out whether I can control the hostname of my MacBook, before I write back to the software company to tell them that their licencing algorithm is incompatible.

Thanks in advance for any help, advice or pointers.

P.S. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Comment: You might get better answers for this on the superuser.com stack

Comment: Ok thanks. Are the two site's linked, or do I need to report the same question to superuser.com?

Comment: They are both part of the stack exchange family but you’ll need to create a new account & question there. :-)

Comment: Nice one, thanks Warren, that sorted it!